# C# Run a program with progressbar to compress listbox items

Tags: c#

I would like to write a custom gui for a compressor.

How is it possible to run the Command Line Interface on all files added into listbox ?
Also how to display a progressbar displaying the current progress (not in % but at least which file is currently processing).

Comment: What compression program you're using ?

Comment: What is your question? Everyone understands it differently as seen in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about just running a command line program, you can use System.Diagnostic.Process.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\path\to\my.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"c:\path\to\filetoCompress.file";
//event wireup

p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_exited);
p.Start();
```

As far as displaying progress for that, you could use the Exited event of the process to wire up to a process bar that shows the progress of number exted vs. number total.

```
void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //assuming you have setup this bar previously.
   pbFilesCommpressProgress.PerformStep();
}
```

Comment: But how to set the command line app to process files added to the listbox ?

Comment: It depends on the command line app and what parameters you need to pass to it. You're going to set up a loop to loop through the elements of the listbox.  This should be the inner part of the loop, i.e. the setup of the process, its command line parameters and running the process after setup.  I cannot give too much more code without your code for context.

Answer (score 0):

In a CLI you can use one of many ASCII characters like ||| or ... and then you can append them as files progress.. or you can denote (file x of xxx), and inform the user of the progress as it occurs.