# Start a process for all items in a listbox

Tags: c#

How is it possible to run a command line app on all checked items in a checkedlistbox ?

I added my files to the listbox with this code:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      var filters = "*.avi|*.mkv";
      odd.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
      if (odd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          string folderName = odd.SelectedPath;
          string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

          foreach (string file in files) checkedListBox1.Items.Add(file, CheckState.Checked);
      }
  }
```

Now i want to that x264.exe with parameters process (convert) all (checked) items  added to the listbox

Comment: Assuming the checkboxes' values are string you send them in as args

Comment: Do you not know how to loop through items in a checkedlistbox or do you not know how to run a command line in C#? What have you tried so far (show your work)?

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail to be answerable. What exactly are you trying to run with the values of the checked items? Are they arguments? Are they separate programs? One program that will act on several different files?

Comment: you asked a question like this before [C# Run a program with progressbar to compress listbox items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274403/c-sharp-run-a-program-with-progressbar-to-compress-listbox-items).These guys really want to help you but they need more details, maybe something you tried which didn't work out well.Help us to help you with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to have fully understood your question but if you want to run a command for each checked element in a checkedlistbox you can use a for each loop through all the checked item :

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {
Process.Start("someapp.exe");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer -- I'm not sure I follow exactly what you're trying to accomplish, however:

If you want to combine all of your items in your list box that are checked into a single statement you could do the following:

```
string commands = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().Aggregate((i,j) =>i + " " + j);
```

Meaning, if your checked list box items were:

```
/t
/run
/something
```

You'd get `/t /run /something`